# How to set the scroll to top after navigating from one page to other in quasar

Tags: typescript, vue.js, scroll, quasar-framework

I have a qlist which when clicked by the user will be redirected to another page.However the scrolled position from the previous page remains the same and is not set to top. So the user has to scroll back to the top inorder to view the contents of the now navigated page. The following code has been used.

.vue file

```
      <q-item
        @Click.native = "scrollToTop"
        clickable
        class="q-item__select"
        active-class="q-item--active"
        id="mainTemplate"
        :to="{
          path: '/project/' + this.project.Id.toString() + '/template',
        }"
      >
```

.ts file (typescript)

```
 public scrollToTop() {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
```

routes.ts

```
const routes = [
  // PROJECT
  // -----
  {
    path: 'project/:projectId',
    name: 'project',
    component: () => import('layouts/masterSlave.vue'),
    props: {
      master: () => import('pages/projects/project/projectDesktop.vue'),
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'architecture',
        name: 'architecturePage',
        component: () => import('src/pages/projects/project/sections/architecture.vue'),
        props: {
          slaveLevel: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'template',
        name: 'templatePage',
        component: () => import('src/pages/projects/project/sections/template.vue'),
        props: {
          slaveLevel: 1,
        },
      },
   ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in router.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

```
scrollBehavior() {
   document.getElementById('app').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

or

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
   return { x: 0, y: 0 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.
I have modified the router like this
const createRouter = () =>
  new VueRouter({
    mode: (Platform.is.electron || Platform.is.capacitor) && !window.Cypress ? 'hash' : 'history',
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
    routes: [],
});
const router = createRouter();
export default router;

Comment: But I get this error.
TS2488: Type '({ path: string; name: string; component: () => Promise<typeof import("/home/projects/project/project.vue")>; } | { path: string; name: string; component: () => Promise<...>; } | ... 12 more ... | { ...; })[] | VueRouter' must  have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. Any help would be appreciated.